# Make Background Black for screen other than popup div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following div which i am showing as popup:

```
    <div id="divOperationMessage" style="background-color: White; border: 2px solid black;
            display: block;  width: 350px; z-index: 1001; top: 60px; left: 240px; position: fixed; 
            padding-left: 10px;margin:auto;">

------------------Whatever content inside-----------------------------

                    </div>
```

When its shown, i can easily view other part of screen in the main background.

Its viewing as below:

[image]

(Entry updated sucessfully is popup div above)

I dont want to show background screen when poup is there.

I want to make it black..

How can i make it black??

I tried with setting opacity to 0.75 ... but that prooved misconceptual...did not solved my purpose..

What can i do for it???

Please help me.

Comment: You want to make popup background black???

Comment: @Richa  not poup background...scrren other than poup

Comment: Can't you just do `background-color: black;`?

Comment: Try jquery modal feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go!

Here's the HTML code:

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="pop-up">
    Content in Pop-up.
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS code:

```css
#overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: none;
}

#pop-up {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  z-index: 1001;
  top: 60px;
  left: 240px;
  position: fixed; 
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I would do:

Create a `fixed` div with 100% width and height;

put the popup div inside this fixed `overlay` and center it horizontally and vertically.

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        Whatever code!!
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.overlay{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: black;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.75)
}

.popup{
    width:300px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:100px;
    margin-left:-150px;
}
```

Update 2020:
I would use `100vh` and `100vw` as it is widely supported. Centering the popup would be done with CSS Grid Layout and aligning the box to center.

```
.overlay{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    background-color: black;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.75)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/NK96D/)**</kbd>

```
if($('#divOperationMessage').length > 0 && $('.mask').length < 1) {
   $('body').append('<span class="mask"></span>'); 
}
```

---

```
.mask {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an overlay div to place over the main content, and below the popup div.

```
div.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75); /*this sets the slightly see-through black*/
    z-index: 100; /*Make this less than the existing popup div*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div id="divOperationMessage" style="background-color: White; border: 2px solid black;display: block;  width: 350px; z-index: 1001; top: 60px; left: 240px; position: fixed;padding-left: 10px;margin:auto;">

------------------Whatever content inside-----------------------------

</div>
<div class = 'black_bg' style = "position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.75;background-color:#000"></div>
```

And whenever you are showing the popup , add this line

```
$('.black_bg').show();
```

Comment: why not just create a class to keep all those styles?

Comment: Use it if you need it. Since the OPs question had only HTML , I used the same format instead of writing it in a seperate class :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna use jquery,you can use jquery **modal feature.**

Easy to use!

**Check here** :

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete all items": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

In this,if you click on the button,or outside of the popup menu,it closes.
You don't have to code down that too.
Short and compacT!

Comment: Providing just a link as an answer ?

Comment: @harsha Link is more than sufficient i guess.

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK yep, good link, but link is generally posted as a comment, not as answer, Thats why he was telling u.

Comment: @AngryTiger Ahh.. *sigh* i know,the rules...
btw I think harsha a 'she'. :D

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK : Harsha is not necessarily a 'she' , depends on the part of India you come from ;)